# Code Igniter, array printing in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my model

```
<?php
     class home_model extends CI_Model {

     function login() 
     {
       $q = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
       $count = $q->num_rows();

       if ($count > 0) 
       {
         foreach ($q->result() as $row) 
         {
            $data[]['username'] = $row->username;
            $data[]['email'] = $row->email;
            $data[]['sex'] = $row->sex;
            $data[]['dob'] = $row->dob;
            $data[]['mobile'] = $row->mobile;
        }
        return $data;
    }
  ?>
```

This is my controller

```
<?php
     if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
       exit('No direct script access allowed');

class home extends CI_Controller 
{
  public function index() 
  {
    $this->load->model('home_model');
    $data['records'] = $this->home_model->login();
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
  }
}
```

I am only able to print_r and that is not how i want it, how will i echo this? I don't know what format I should use in my echo,

```
echo($records[0]);
```

This format is what I tried but it returns the error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: views/home.php
>
> Line Number: 4 Array
>
> How should I code my view?

Comment: Use `foreach` to display array of values.

Comment: i tried foreach($records as $d) then <?php echo($d['username']); ?> still doesnt work

Comment: $records in view is the same as $data in model.

Comment: so with this controller and model, how should i write view?

Comment: $this->load->view('pagename', $data['records']);

Comment: `print_r($records)` in view and paste the result !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following process

Your Modal

```
 function login() 
 {
   $q = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
   $count = $q->num_rows();

   if ($count > 0) 
   {
      return $q->result();
   }
 }
?>
```

No change for controller

On View

```
foreach ($records as $row) 
{
    $username = $row->username;
    $email = $row->email;
    $sex = $row->sex;
    $dob = $row->dob;
    $mobile = $row->mobile;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all your login function is need to corrected as per codeigniter.

```
function login() {
$q = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
$count = $q->num_rows();
if ($count > 0) {

    return $q->result_array();
}
```

it will provide an array as you required.

then to use in views, you need to use it following.

suppose you want to echo first user name

```
        echo $records[0]['username'];
```

Here $records[0] is an array and hence you need to use as above mention and similarly for other field.

Answer (score 0):

In your views

```
foreach($records as $users)
{

    echo $users['username'];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin function `print_r()` and provide the array is an argument